# Convert string (url style) to navigate in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

Current string: `folder1/folder2/folder3`

I need to convert in: `['folder1']['folder2']['folder3']`

What I tried:

```
let folder = "folder1/folder2/folder3";

let splittedFolder = folder.split('/');
let newFolder = splittedFolder.join('[' ']');
```

I think I am absolutely wrong.... I want to achieve somethink like `userDB['folder1']['folder2']['folder3']` to navigate into an Object and edit it.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array? Or a string containing `[]`?

Comment: A string containing `[]` to go deeper in object :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might split by slashes, then map to enclose each string with `['']`s, then join again:

```js
let folder = "folder1/folder2/folder3";
const output = folder
  .split('/')
  .map(str => `['${str}']`)
  .join('');
console.log(output);
```

But you can't navigate a normal object with a string like this unless you use `eval`, which you really shouldn't use. If the literal code

```
userDB['folder1']['folder2']['folder3']
```

would result in accessing the desired nested value, then to get to it from your input, use `reduce` instead:

```
const val = folder.split('/')
  .reduce((a, key) => a[key], userDB);
```

Or, to handle possible undefined objects in between:

```
const val = folder.split('/')
  .reduce((a, key) => a !== undefined ? a[key] : undefined, userDB);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) But how do I can remove the first? because will be an empty one: `['']`

Comment: Do you mean that your real input string has a leading slash? If so, slice it off first. `folder.slice(1).split(...`

Comment: Thanks so much :) Your example from above works well. I get the value from the object. But what if I want to change this value? `val = newValue;` not works because the variable `val` "is never used", also if I change to `let val`...

Comment: Pop off the last substring from the array first, then use the same `reduce` method as above to get `lastObj` (while iterating over all but the last item in the array), then do `lastObj[lastProp] = newVal`